# Struggling with select in a form ( and react hooks )

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I just do not manage to implement a select option into my form

How can I call this easy select, with my "handleChangeTimezone" thats already working on inputs form ?

**working without Select**

```
<form>

  <label for="email"> Username :  </label>
  <input 
    type="text" 
    onChange={(e)=>handleChangeUsername(e.target.value)}
  />

 <label for="timzone"> Timezone :  </label>
  <input 
    type="text" 
    onChange={(e)=>handleChangeTimezone(e.target.value)}
  />
    
</form>
```

**with Select this is what it should look like**
but says "handleChangeTimezone" is undefined

```
import Select from 'react-select';

const options = [
  { value: 'london', label: 'London' },
  { value: 'new-york', label: 'New-york' },
  { value: 'tokyo', label: 'Tokyo' },
];

<form>

  <label for="email"> Username :  </label>
  <input 
    type="text" 
    onChange={(e)=>handleChangeUsername(e.target.value)}
  />

 <label for="timzone"> Timezone :  </label>
   <Select 
     onChange={(e) => handleChangeTimezone(e.target.value)}
     options={options}
   />
    
</form>
```

**as requested the full setTimezoneEl** plus some fetching working for inputs.

```
const [timezoneEl, setTimezoneEl] = useState('')
const handleChangeTimezone= e => {
    setTimezoneEl(e.target.value)
  }

const handleEditProfile = async () => {

    const creds = {
      user: {
        username: usernameEl,
        timezone: timezoneEl
      }
    };

    const config = {
      method: 'PUT',
      mode: 'cors',
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${Cookies.get('token')}`
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(creds)
    };

    const res = await fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}api/users/${id}`, config);
    console.log(res)
    try {

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
  }
```

also my actual input looks more like this, had to change it a bit for the purpose of the question

```
<label for="email"> Username :  </label>
  <input 
    type="text" 
     onChange={handleChangeTimezone}}
  />
```

Comment: I just did that sir

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you wouldn't just plug in the same `handleTimezoneChange` function here either by passing it as a prop (can't tell what your component tree is like) or just redefining it.. but the issue here is that you aren't invoking `setSelectedOption` in the `onChange`.

Should use a callback like you did with the input form

```
onChange={(e) => setSelectedOption(e.target.value)}
```

Comment: I've tried its rendering an undefined, this is what makes me confused.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I resolved my problem :

````
 <select onChange={(e) => setTimezoneEl(e.target.value)} id="timezone">
        <option defaultValue hidden>
          {getData.data?.attributes?.timezone}
        </option>
        {timezones.map((option, index) => (
          <option value={option.label} key={index}>
            {option.label}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    ```
````